# How do you show message from controller to view in magento?

Tags: php, magento

I will like to show message from controller to view in magento.
In controller I have

```
    $arrError=Mage::getModel('advert/advert')->isValid(array('step1','step2'));
        if (!empty($arrError)) {
            $strReturnPath = $arrError['return_path'];
            unset($arrError['return_path']);
            foreach ($arrError as $strError) {
                Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->addError( $strError );
                //var_dump($strError);

            }

            $this->_redirect($strReturnPath);
        }

        $this->loadLayout();
        $this->_initLayoutMessages('customer/session');

        $this->renderLayout();
```

And in view I have

```
<div id="messages_product_error_view">
    <?php

        Mage::app()->getLayout()->getMessagesBlock()->setMessages(Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getMessages(true));
        echo  Mage::app()->getLayout()->getMessagesBlock()->toHtml();
    ?>
</div>
```

In controller when I do a var_dump I can see the error messages. With redirect, the page does redirect to the view page. However, in the div I expect the message to be shown. **ANd it is not showing** Please please please help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think `_redirect()` method in controller does not stop script execution. It only sets up redirect headers. Because of that it still process loading layout, initializing layout messages and rendering it. This will make magento read messages in the same process and clear them before the actual redirect. Try adding this code after calling `_redirect()` method

```
$this->getResponse()->sendResponse();
```

or rearrange your code in this manner:

```
if (!empty($arrError)) {
        $strReturnPath = $arrError['return_path'];
        unset($arrError['return_path']);
        foreach ($arrError as $strError) {
            Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->addError( $strError );
            //var_dump($strError);

        }

        $this->_redirect($strReturnPath);
    }
 else {
    $this->loadLayout();
    $this->_initLayoutMessages('customer/session');

    $this->renderLayout();
 }
```

Comment: Thanks.. Tried both aka tried to add the send Response and also by rearranging.. However, in both cases, I end up with the same as before. The message does not show up on Page 1 which is the page that is passes in the redirect. Any help please

Answer (score 0):

When you debug Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getMessages(true) in your view, does it contain any of the messages?

If you want to understand Magento notification better, you may find more about it [here](http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/magento/magento-frontend/utilizing-magento-notification-system/).

Answer (score 0):

```
Mage::app()->getLayout()->getMessagesBlock()->setMessages(Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getMessages(true));
```

was resetting my session . As a result, I was lossing the messages. Crap! Damn! Bugger!

Anyway, by removing the line I have the solution working.